# Dynamically assigning a function prop on a Vue component

Tags: vuejs3, cropperjs

I'm using the [vue-cropperjs](https://github.com/Agontuk/vue-cropperjs) wrapper, and rendering a list of these components using a v-for

```
 <div v-for="(data, index) in mylist"
        :key="index">
      
        <vue-cropper
          :view-mode="2"
          :zoomable="true"
          :scalable="true"
          ref="cropper"
          :src=".."
          @cropend=".."/>
        
      </div>
```

This `ref=cropper` is a reactive variable/composable that I have access to in another component as well. I'm not setting the `@ready` function prop in my `vue-cropper` above because I don't care for running a method on all croppers, however, if in another component user does action X for an index i, I do want to set the data using `setData` method on that particular vue-cropper instance like `cropper.value[index].setData({data})`, but this does not work and I suppose this is because the cropper on that index is not ready yet as per cropper-js documentation.

How do I from another component's script, without setting a ready property on my v-for loop for all vue-croppers, instead execute this `cropper.value[index].setData()` method after that particular cropper is ready when I'm calling this.

I tried doing this, however this does not seem to work in Vue 3, and I'm getting a `.$on is not a function` error:

```
cropper.value[index].$on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Cropper is ready!');
        cropper.value[index].setData({data})   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was accessed the underlying element of the cropper component and attaching an event listener to that element, and it worked.

```
const element = cropperInstance.$el;
element.addEventListener("ready", () => { 
     //code
})
```